# Relative weighting between fields of a property elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to set up a search engine for a project that analyzes a `title` property in three ways.

1. standard text matching
2. ngram analysis
3. keyword matching

I would also like the relative scoring of any matches found with those analyses weighted in the same precedence.

Here is my current mapping for this

```
{
    "properties": {
        "title": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "standard",
            "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "boost: 1
                },
                "ngram": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "custom_ngram_analyzer",
                    "boost": 2
                }
            },
            "boost": 4
        },
        {... Other fields ...}
    }
}
```

I am searching using a multi match

```
"query" => array(
        "multi_match" => array(
            "query" => $query,
            "type" => "best_fields",
            "fields" => array("title", "title.*", ...Other fields...),
            "tie_breaker" => 0.3,
            "minimum_should_match" => "30%"
        )
    )
);
```

Is this the best way to be going about applying these custom weights (in the order specefied at the top of this question)? I am not too experienced with ElasticSearch so I probably am going wrong somewhere.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To include custom weights in your `multi_match query` you should write it like this:

```
"query" => array(
        "multi_match" => array(
            "query" => $query,
            "fields" => array("title^10", "tags^5", "content^3" ...Other fields...),
            "tie_breaker" => 0.3,
            "minimum_should_match" => "30%"
        )
    )
);
```

And the query type shouldn't be `best_field` in your case. you should leave it for default value.
As you can see with new query you can explicitly define weight for each field.
to debug the weights it's very good to use `explain` parameter in you'r query so you can track down to final score for each document.